# How to set a thumbnail image of a video in a cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, cell

I have been trying to set a thumbnail image from a video that I query from parse.com
 but having no luck. Here is my code for the thumbnail:

```
- (UIImage *)thumbnailFromVideoAtURL:(NSURL *)url
    {
    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];

    //  Get thumbnail at the very start of the video
    CMTime thumbnailTime = [asset duration];
    thumbnailTime.value = 0;

    //  Get image from the video at the given time
    AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;

    CGImageRef imageRef = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:thumbnailTime actualTime:NULL error:NULL];
    UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return thumbnail;
}
```

It works with `viewDidLoad` in a normal view controller but I do not know how to set it in `UITableViewController` in the cell's. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

In your `UITableViewDataSource` protocols implementation:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

NSString *cellIdentifier = @"yourellIdentifier";

CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellIdentifier];

NSURL* videoURL = videos[indexPath.row];

...
[cell loadPhotoFromURL: videoURL];
...

 return cell;
}
```

You have to implement your custom Cell:

CustomCell.h

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *thumbnaliImageView;
```

CustomCell.m

```
#pragma mark - thumbnal loading
- (void)loadPhotoFromURL:(NSURL*)url
{
    [self.thumbnaliImageView  setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Stub"];
    self.thumbnaliImageView.image = image;
    self.thumbnaliImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {


     AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];

    //  Get thumbnail at the very start of the video
    CMTime thumbnailTime = [asset duration];
    thumbnailTime.value = 0;

    //  Get image from the video at the given time
    AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;

    CGImageRef imageRef = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:thumbnailTime actualTime:NULL error:NULL];
    UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

        if(thumbnail){
            // do UI stuff back in UI land
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                self.thumbnaliImageView.image = thumbnail;

            });

        }
    });

}

}
```

Comment: Offloading work to background is a good idea but you can mix up images due to cell reuse.

Comment: To prevent the mixing I did initialize the  self.thumbnaliImageView.image with place holder image, before downloading.

Comment: The problem is that you have captured self in the main_queue block and when the block is going to be executed the self cell can be reused for different row and thus should have different image. It might not be the problem in the end of scrolling but you pictures may flicker while you scroll.

Comment: Any way, this few lines of code is not full solution, but one of possible ways to solution! :)

Comment: I have written the comment just to point that if someone copy/pastes this he can have troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Use CustomCell

```
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell;
    if(indexPath.row != [Array count] )
    {
       cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
        }

        NSString *imageurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arraysearchVideoList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"imageUrl"]];
        [cell.ImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageurl]
                       placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"noimage.png"]];
        [cell.ImageView addSubview:image];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way,
Make a custom cell in it give the imageview tag 
and in table's cellForRowAtIndexPath method apply this code:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier1;
        CellIdentifier1 = @"contactList";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];

        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *ar = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [ar objectAtIndex:1];

        }
    UIImageView *imgContact = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:TAG_CONTACTIMAGE]
     imgContact.image = [self thumbnailFromVideoAtURL:url];
    }
```